# LaunchDaemons and Environment Variables

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, environment-variables, startup

For a while now, I've been noticing that my MacPorts-installed Apache2 instance hasn't been starting when I start up ([MacPorts Apache2 Stopped Launching on Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042992/macports-apache2-stopped-launching-on-boot)). The LaunchDaemon is loaded. Today I bumped into something in a log file that may point to an answer, but I can't find any confirmation.

I use environment variables in my `httpd.conf` file. Specifically, the `${HOME}` variable. Is it possible (or probable, etc.) that environmental variables are fully loaded when LaunchDaemons are executed? I can add them to the `plist` file, but I'm hoping someone can provide me with a decent, high level look into the boot process of OS X and confirm what I think I'm seeing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this page about the Boot Process](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/BootProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002130) on MacOSX, which contains some information. Basically, `launchd` is started and run as root. Every daemons is then started by `launchd` based on the [`plist`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) file.

Regarding the environment during daemon start, I have not find a single bit of explicit information. But after reading the [launchctl](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) man, I found a command that can print out the environment of `launchd`. So the trick is to go `root` and ask:

```
#$> sudo su
Password:
#$> whoami
root
#$> launchctl
launchd% export
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"; export PATH;
launchd% exit
#$> exit
```

I infer that the print environment is the one used when daemons are started. If you repeat the operation without going `root`, the environment must match the user's one.

Comment: Great information, thanks. I found similar info yesterday and the short version seems to be that the ${HOME} directory has no real meaning at launch. At least not the meaning I need/want it to have.

Comment: Yep, I guess you will have to put your environment into the plist.

Comment: So I added a value to my `environment.plist` file, but in order to prevent conflicts, I decided to try setting a custom variable named `HTTPD_CONF_BASE_PATH`. That seemed like a good idea, but Apache doesn't seem to like my custom value. It errors saying that `<path/to/my/httpd.conf>/${HTTPD_CONF_BASE_PATH}/includes` doesn't exist.